# xlsxwriter unable to write more than 1,048,576 rows to multiple tables and worksheets

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I have found that xlsxwriter supports the limits set by Excel Total number of       1,048,576 rows by 16,384 columns rows and columns on a worksheet.
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3
https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html?highlight=1%2C048%2C576

As my data is more than 1048576 row I am writing it to a unique table in a unique worksheet, I have tried setting the limit to 1000000 rows per table per worksheet and I get multiple tables and worksheets but only up to 1,048,576 rows.

I guess the question is can the workbook support more than 1,048,576 rows? If so there seems to be a problem, anybody any experience in writing beyond that?

Thanks

Comment: Do you need to use excel? Because you technically could use a database or just a csv.

Comment: Unfortunately, yes.

Comment: You will need to use multiple sheets then

Comment: I have, and still cannot go over a total of 1048576 rows, its like the workbook has a max of 1048576, but can;t find any documentation to support that.

Comment: From the [docs](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html): "_XlsxWriter supports Excels worksheet limits of 1,048,576 rows by 16,384 columns._"

Comment: Yeah, I pointed that out in my post, and also says you can have multiple worksheets per workbook. So implicitly I should be able to have more than worksheet each with 1048576 rows, as I can do in Excel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> can the workbook support more than 1,048,576 rows?

No. That is the maximum row number that Excel supports per worksheet.

**Update**:

Here is an example that creates 1,048,576 rows in 2 worksheets:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('row_file.xlsx')

for _ in range(2):
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

    for row in range(1048576):
        worksheet.write(row, 0, 'Hello')

workbook.close()
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and a great module! The Excel limitation I can find is 1048576 rows per worksheet, I have just created a Workbook with two worksheets, each with 1048576 rows, using the fill function. I was able to save them and edit them. I can't find the workbook limitation.

Comment: The limit is per worksheet. There isn’t any limit on the number of rows in the workbook (i.e. multiple worksheets).

Comment: I've updated with an example that creates the 1,048,576 rows in 2 worksheets to demonstrate that there isn't a workbook limit.

Comment: Thanks for the additional clarification, just did an exhaustive test and finally generated a 7 column, 26+ million row workbook, took a while to write, but it completed. Many thanks for your work.